# EF OData MySql Unknown column 'Project3.x' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, odata, automapper-5

I'm using OData V4, EF6 and MySql 5.6/5.7
With below models and tables. I get the result of the Application resource fine with this call odata/Applications but I get this error when I expand on roles, as follows odata/Applications?$expand=roles.

Error: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. Unknown column 'Project3.ApplicationId' in 'where clause'

I know it's something with mapping, but I can't see what.

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

    //public virtual Application Application { get; set; }

}

public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public Application()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
    }
}

public class ApplicationView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RoleView> Roles { get; set; }

    public ApplicationView()
    {
        Roles = new List<RoleView>();
    }
}

public class RoleView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

}

create table IF NOT EXISTS Application (
ApplicationId int not null auto_increment primary key,
Name varchar(255) not null,
IsDeleted bool not null default false,

CreatedBy varchar(255) not null,
CreatedOn Datetime not null,
UpdatedBy varchar(255) not null,
UpdatedOn DateTime not null
```

) ENGINE=INNODB;

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS Role (
RoleId int not null auto_increment primary key,
Name varchar(255) not null,
ApplicationId int not null,

CreatedBy varchar(255) not null,
CreatedOn Datetime not null,
UpdatedBy varchar(255) not null,
UpdatedOn DateTime not null,

index app_index (ApplicationId),
foreign key (ApplicationId) references Application(ApplicationId) on delete cascade
```

) ENGINE=INNODB;

This is the OData action method.

```
[HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("Applications")]
    public IQueryable<ApplicationView> Get()
    {
        var result = IdentityRepository.Applications
            .Include("Role")
            .ProjectTo<ApplicationView>();
        return result;
    }
```

The mapping classes:

```
public class RoleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public RoleMap()
    {
        ToTable("Role");

        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("RoleId");

        // Tried with/without, no change.
        //HasRequired(x => x.Application).WithMany(x => x.Roles).HasForeignKey(x => x.ApplicationId);
    }
}

public class ApplicationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Application>
{
    public ApplicationMap()
    {
        ToTable("Application");

        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ApplicationId");

        // Tried with/without no change.
        HasMany(x => x.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.ApplicationId);
    }
}
```

I tried the repository with both code first and database first edmx and keep getting the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't `.Include("Role")` be `.Include("Roles")`?

Comment: I've tried that, as plural or not, same exact error. i.e. Include("Roles")

Answer (score 0):

The EF mappings seem correct. My guess is that the problem comes from the `ProjectTo` method. This seems to be part of AutoMapper Queryable Extensions. [The documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) says (about `ProjectTo`):

> Note that for this feature to work, all type conversions must be
>   explicitly handled in your Mapping. For example, you can not rely on
>   the ToString() override of the Item class to inform entity framework
>   to only select from the Name column, and any data type changes, such
>   as Double to Decimal must be explicitly handled as well.

Try replacing in your query `ProjectTo` by a `Select`, or plain removing it, to confirm if the error comes from there, or check your AutoMapper mappings.

Comment: I thought of the auto mapper and I apologize I forgot to add my mappings o here they are. I even got rid of the ProjectTo<> and just returned the object model, i.e.

return IdentityRepository.Applications.Include("Roles");

Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.CreateMap<Market, MarketView>();
                x.CreateMap<Application, ApplicationView>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Roles, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Roles));
                x.CreateMap<Role, RoleView>();
                x.CreateMap<AppUser, AppUserView>();
            });

Comment: Hi, I still haven't figured this issue out. I really hope someone can shed some light.

Comment: Okay, some ideas: check that your model is synchronized with your database, it seems the query generated by EF does not match the real database schema. If you do `Add-Migration Test` do you get something in the Up/Down methods? If you do, your db is not up to date. Also, take a look at the real SQL generated by your query, try running it manually against your database. More ideas: are you sure you are connecting to the right database? And that `Project3` prefix, is it the name of your database, does it make sense as your table name prefix, does it appear anywhere in the code?

Comment: Hi Diana,

Thanks for your input. Yes I am connected to the right DB, and no the Project3 is not the name of my DB, I don't have anything called "Project", I see the generated SQL, but it doesn't contain Project3, this is happening on the OData $expand=scopes call. I also took your input on the Add-Migration, and compared the result to my DB, they match as far as columns go, however EF is not creating some of the FKs on some of the tables that have the FKs.

Comment: As for the FKs not being generated, I restarted VS2015 and re-ran Add-Migrate on a new file and now they're all there. However, same issue with the Project3.